# Using same partial view for edit and new operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

- .NET 4.51, MVC 5

I have a view **Edit.cshtml** as follows:

```
@model EnergyMission.Country.Dtos.GetCountryOutput

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Country";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}             

@Html.Partial("_AddEditPartial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "ActionName", "Edit" } })
```

and then **New.cshtml** as follows:

```
@model EnergyMission.Country.Dtos.GetNewCountryOutput

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Country";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_AddEditPartial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "ActionName", "Create" } })
```

Note from the above that:

1. Each one has a different model namely **GetCountryOutput** and **GetNewCountryOutput**. Both of these have the **same** properties. Currently they cannot be made the same class for other reasons.
2. I pass the action name so that I can use it in the **Html.BeginForm** in the partial view
3. I still need to figure out how to pass the model type to the partial view

The **_AddEditPartial.cshtml** looks as follows:

```
@model  EnergyMission.Country.Dtos.GetCountryOutput

<h3>@ViewData["ActionName"]</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm(@ViewData["ActionName"], "Countries"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CountryTableModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbbreviationCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AbbreviationCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AbbreviationCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternationalCountryDialCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InternationalCountryDialCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InternationalCountryDialCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there an easier way to share a common data entry layout for Add / Edit operations that whay I am doing above?

If I were to follow the approach described how do I:

2. Pass the model type to the partial view. Is it something like:

_

```
@Html.Partial("_AddEditPartial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "ActionName", "Create" }, {"ModelTypeName", "EnergyMission.Country.Dtos.GetCountryOutput"} })
```

and then in _AddEdit.cshtml

_

```
@model  typeof(@ViewData["ModelTypeName"])
```

3. Why is the following not valid:

_

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewData["ActionName"], "Countries"))
```

as that gives me a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single view, then use your controller to direct to a single view and use your repository to insert/update accordingly in a Save method. However, please note, in the example below you will need to make sure the model is the same - based on the principle that you should remove duplication. If that's not possible consider using a dynamic model in your view or using the ViewModel you can map the properties accordingly (anyway I don't want to over complicate the answer as I'm hoping this provides the solution you need - give or take some refactoring here and there).

A simplified example of the controller and repository (using a viewmodel)....

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   private IProductRepository _repository;
   public ProductController(IProductRepository productsRepository)
   {
       this._repository = productsRepository;
   }

    public ViewResult Edit(int productID)
    {
        ProductEditViewModel model = new ProductEditViewModel
        {
            Product = this._repository.Products.Where(m => m.ProductID == productID).FirstOrDefault()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int productId)
    {
        ProductEditViewModel model = new ProductEditViewModel
        {
            Product = _repository.Products.First(m => m.ProductID == productId)
        };

        TryUpdateModel(model);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.Save(model.Product);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        return View("Edit", new Product());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        return Edit(product.ProductID);
     }
 }
```

The repository....

```
public class SqlProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
     private MyDataContext db;
     private Table<Product> _productsTable; 

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _productsTable; }
    }
    public void Save(Product product)
    {
        if (product.ProductID == 0)
        {
            _productsTable.InsertOnSubmit(product);
        }
        else if (_productsTable.GetOriginalEntityState(product) == null)
        {
            _productsTable.Attach(product);
            _productsTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, product);
        }
        _productsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks for this. I used this as the basis for what I finally implemented.

Comment: Glad it was useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to 3. is that html.beginform expects a string as its first parameter, and as you are using ViewData which is a

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

you need to cast your value as a string:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewData["ActionName"] as string, "Countries"))
```

For 1. You could try deriving both of your dto classes from a base class and setting that class as the model type for both the add and edit views

Comment: thanks for the BeginForm fix. I realise I can derive from the same base class, but for other reasons (ie I don't control that class hierachy) I need to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: I see, then an approach that may work is to use your own viewmodels and then simplify the process of moving data in and out of those into the your dtos by using a mapper utility like automapper or valueinjector